# How to fix "syntax error at or near "$1" with asyncpg API

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

I'm trying to insert value in a table of a postgresql database by using query arguments via asyncpg API.
I created my table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    cat BIGINT,
    roles BIGINT ARRAY
);
```

I already tried to directly cast the argument in BIGINT like this : `$1:BIGINT` but I get the same error

```
await connection.execute('''
        INSERT INTO my_table(cat, roles)
        VALUES($1, $2)
        ON CONFLICT ($1)
        DO UPDATE SET roles = array_append(roles, $2)
        ''', cat, roles)
```

cat is a int and roles a int array

It is supposed to insert cat and roles into my_table but I just got the error : `syntax error at or near "$1"`

I provide the logs of the database just in case

```
2019-01-26 21:01:22 UTC:172.31.36.115(37598):Barbote@Barbotedb:[15082]:ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" at character 111
2019-01-26 21:01:22 UTC:172.31.36.115(37598):Barbote@Barbotedb:[15082]:STATEMENT: 
INSERT INTO "429792212016955423"(cat, roles)
VALUES($1 $2)
ON CONFLICT ($1)
DO UPDATE SET roles = array_append(roles, $2);
```

Comment: it seems you have a typo on your await connection.execute line (execute is spelled exceute.) also i think you would want ON CONFLICT (cat) since this has nothing to do with the positional argument that you give to values.

Comment: I made a mistake when I copied my code sry.
I changed the ON CONFLICT part and I now have a new error
`column reference "roles" is ambigious`

Comment: Can `roles` contain duplicates?

Comment: I just needed to write it like that `my_table.roles`
I got an other error now again
`there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`
Should I edit my post or create a new one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a primary key (or unique columns) to use `ON CONFLICT`, so you have to define the table as

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    cat BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, -- !!
    roles BIGINT ARRAY
);
```

The column `roles` is ambiguous in `UPDATE`, fix it specifing the table name:

```
await connection.execute('''
        INSERT INTO my_table(cat, roles)
        VALUES($1, $2)
        ON CONFLICT (cat)
        DO UPDATE SET roles = array_cat(my_table.roles, $2)
        ''', cat, roles)
```

Note that the function `array_append()` appends an element to an array. You can use `array_cat()` instead. However, it may lead to duplicated elements in a single array. If your aim is to have distinct elements in arrays, you should define a custom function in Postgres:

```
create or replace function public.array_merge(anyarray, anyarray)
returns anyarray language sql
as $function$
    select 
        array(
            select unnest($1)
            union
            select unnest($2)
            order by unnest
        )
$function$;
```

and use it instead of `array_cat()`.